# Google places autocomplete widget using the Basic SKU but still getting charged

Tags: google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I'm using the Google places autocomplete widget and since Google applied the billing changes the widget is becoming very costly to maintain. I have added the basic parameters which are supposed to be free but when I view the billing I'm still getting charged for the SKU: Autocomplete without Places Details – Per Session. This is the code I'm using:

```
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
searchBox.setFields(['place_id', 'name', 'types']);
```

So my question is, is there a way to get the autocomplete dropdown without getting charged with the new google places API?

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the **[setFields()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#get_place_information)** method is only applicable when a user selects a place from the autocomplete suggestions. When a place is selected, a [Places Details](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/usage-and-billing#places-details) request is made which is the one that generates Data SKUs (Basic, Contact, and/or Atmosphere), depending on the fields that are specified in the request. If you specify Basic Data in your Places Details request, you will be billed for the Places Details request and not for any additional [Data SKUs](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/usage-and-billing#contact-data) (like Atmosphere and Contact Data) when a user selects a place.

In your case you are only charged for all autocomplete requests and not with any Data SKU. To explain the charge that you got for SKU: [Autocomplete without Places Details – Per Session](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use#ac-no-details-session), you are  charged for this for the times when a user has not selected any place from the autocomplete suggestions within a few minutes of the beginning of the session. This happens when a user only types characters in the autocomplete input box but is not selecting any place from the search results.

If you have setup your billing account, you will be entitled to the recurring $200 monthly free credits. 
Currently, since API requests are charged as per the **[pricing](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/)**, if you want to stay in the free tier usage, you can cap your API usage by setting a [daily limit](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_cap) to them. This is to avoid unexpected charges by limiting the number of API calls you can make per day.

Hope this clarifies it.

Answer (score 0):

The pricing for implementing the autocomplete SearchBox is different than using the autocomplete widget. The searchbox uses the places text search functionality, which automatically bills for all three places data categories. The widget, however, allows you to mask data fields and automatically creates a session that begins when the user starts typing and ends when a selection is made. With the searchbox, you are getting billed per end user keystroke, which will rack up your charges incredibly fast. I highly recommend implementing the widget over the searchbox.